# Deploy Docker image from Nexus into AWS through Jenkins

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, bitbucket, nexus

At the moment, I have an application build and deploy into AWS through Jenkins triggered by pushes on BitBucket. Generated Docker images are store on a Nexus repository.

I would like to have a process (in Jenkins most probably) where users manually specify a version number and an environment type (prod, preprod, etc). Then the process will get the specific Docker image on Nexus and will deploy it on the specific AWS environment.

What could be the different steps and components to use to set up this process? The final idea is to build a process to back up or deploy previous specific version without pushing on BitBucket.